# C#. Исключение при многопоточной работе с Queue

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Сушествует класс очереди последовательного порта, который работает в своем потоке.
Данные для очереди могут поступать из других потоков.
При разматывании очереди классом последовательным порта возникает исключение:

```
2017/10/15 08:52:36.907|Error|Ошибка работы с портом: COM4. ОШИБКА: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified after the enumerator was instantiated.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CommunicationDevices.Behavior.ExhangeBehavior.SerialPortBehavior.ChannelManagement.ChannelManagementExchangeBehavior.<OneTimeExchangeService>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\Git\Autodictor\src\CommunicationDevices\Behavior\ExhangeBehavior\SerialPortBehavior\ChannelManagement\ChannelManagementExchangeBehavior.cs:line 46
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Communication.SerialPort.MasterSerialPort.<RunExchange>d__38.MoveNext() in C:\Git\Autodictor\src\Communication\SerialPort\MasterSerialPort.cs:line 214
```

Проанализировав стэк вызовов, видно что виновником является InDataQueue.Any(), т.к. Приводится InDataQueue к IEnumerable, а из другого потока я могу добавить данные в InDataQueue, что приведет к исключению.
OneTimeExchangeService - ВЫЗЫВАЕТСЯ ИЗ ПОТОКА ПОРТА.

```
protected override async Task OneTimeExchangeService(MasterSerialPort port, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var inData = (InDataQueue != null && InDataQueue.Any()) ? InDataQueue.Dequeue() : null;  //хранит адресс устройства.
    if (inData != null)
    {
        WriteProvider.InputData = inData;
        DataExchangeSuccess = await Port.DataExchangeAsync(TimeRespone, WriteProvider, ct);
    }
}
```

Наверно  можно InDataQueue.Any() заменить на InDataQueue.Count > 0.
А как правильно работать с такими коллекциями, возможно есть специальные многопоточные коллекции, как с ними работать и в чем отличие?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Полагаю, что многопоточная очередь ConcurrentQueue<T> (могу ошибаться, вдруг там нет такой проблемы) тут не поможет. Нужно защищать от модификации через lock. Или материализовывать очередь в список каждый раз перед обходом. Или своя очередь-обертка, оптимизированная под это (имхо лучшее)

Comment: Спасибо. попробую  ConcurrentQueue, в ней есть IsEmpty и TryDequeue, которые применяются при извлечении элементов, вроде при добавлении пробелм нет и метод обычный Enqueue                          
 UniversalInputType inData = null;
  if ((InDataQueue != null && !InDataQueue.IsEmpty && 
       InDataQueue.TryDequeue(out inData)))

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое решение — используйте внешнюю блокировку. Заведите объект синхронизации и на время работы с очередью лочьте его.

Получится что-то такое:

```
object queueGuard = new object();
protected override async Task OneTimeExchangeService(
        MasterSerialPort port, CancellationToken ct)
{
    DataT inData; // или какой у вас там тип данных у элементов InDataQueue
    lock (queueGuard)
    {
        inData = (InDataQueue != null && InDataQueue.Any()) ?
                InDataQueue.Dequeue() : null;  //хранит адрес устройства.
    }
    if (inData != null)
    {
        WriteProvider.InputData = inData;
        DataExchangeSuccess = await Port.DataExchangeAsync(TimeRespone, WriteProvider, ct);
    }
}
```

Не забудьте использовать один и тот же объект `queueGuard` при всех операциях доступа к `InDataQueue`.

Comment: спасибо, я думал про lock, если не найду другого решения. Пока ограничусь использовангием ConcurrentQueue. Вроде на тестах все получается при изменении размеров очереди из нескольких потоков.